# Weapon building in post apocalyptic situation?

Tags: weapons, post-apocalypse

Let's suppose that some part of population survives an almost massive extinction event that also destroys most of the planet's infrastructure (nuclear war, whatever) but still preserving some of actual  knowledge. What kind of firearms could they build without electric machinery, just anvil and hammer? Muskets? More advanced rifles with case ammunition? What kind of powder could they produce?

Comment: What kinds of weapons did they use in the First World War, when there were no electric machine tools in use in any weapons factory in the world? Or, if you prefer, in the [Franco-Prussian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Prussian_War), forty years earlier? Or in the American War of Secession? Or in the [Crimean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_War)? And so on, decade after decade downtime.

Comment: P.S. The first all-metal mass-produced cartridge was the Smith and Wesson .22 Short, introduced in 1857. The first mass-produced rifle which used integrated (paper with a metallic base) cartridges was the [Dreyse needle gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyse_needle_gun); more than a million were made between 1840 and 1870.

Comment: Does the metal remain as scrap?   Because we've used up most easily mined metal

Comment: why do the host of other questions about post apocalyptic weapon production not answer your question.

Comment: @Mary: No, we did not use most easily mined metal., not even close. Iron and aluminium ore is literally everywhere, and it is not even conceivable to ever run out. Copper ore is not as ubiquitous, but it is still plentiful, especially if we allow a moderate increase in the price. But then, of course, in a post-apocalyptic situation nobody would be *mining* for metals when there are vast amount of metals already smelted and just lying around to be taken.

Comment: We had mass-production of weapons before we had industrialization or electricity. That just requires repeatable processes, not necessarily powered processes.

Comment: Interesting. I think my misconception comes mostly from thinking that a post apocalyptic setting involves the destruction of the society and some advantages like organized mining (to produce metal in large amounts), large industries to convert that metal in quality alloys, etc. One answer I read here states that producing bullet primers with mercury requires electricity to create nitric acid.

Comment: how far in the future are we talking about? like, did the bomb drop 2 year ago? or are we one if not two century post cataclysm?

do you want  people to still be small group or owuld society have started to form again?

Comment: @AlexP  Whether it was available as scrap was literally my question.  Depending on the disaster, it might not be.

Answer (score 2):

With the preservation of knowledge, everything is producible.

What electric machinery (I'm presuming you mean CNC machines/3d Printers) do is, is to combine many operations into one process and do it with a consistent level of precision...

However, with hand tools *and the proper measuring equipment*, it's possible to build all manner of very complex components.

I would even go so far as to say that if the knowledge of metalworking is maintained, then it isn't a stretch to say that people would be able to produce small bench lathes/milling machines (which are less mechanically complex than a Firearm) - which, even if powered by humans or a waterwheel with a gear reduction or other non-electric means (Cows? Horses?) - would mean that the ability to make complex firearms and full-auto firearms and the associated ammunition would be relatively easy.

The only factor is the time taken to produce - it would take several days to a week of a skilled Gunsmith/Metalworker to make a single Firearm, whereas today with a CNC, a major component (say an Upper or Lower reciever) takes an average shop about 45 mins per component, a shop with a modern CNC about 15 minutes and I've seen some people reckoning they *could* do it in under 5...

If you assume that each major component (Upper, Lower, Barrel, Gas Block, Trigger assembly, Buffer Tube, buttstock, grip and sights) take 45 minutes each - that's about 8 hours of machine (approx) and then a gunsmith can put together an AR build from good quality components in about 30 mins.

Getting back to your post-apoc world - to give some real-world examples - there's the work by John Moses Browning, there's the Owen sub Machine gun from Australia (made in a shed) - but perhaps most relevent to your premise - is the PA Luty Sub machine gun (which was a protest gun, made entirely from non-firearm parts by and English engineer to point out the pointlessness of Gun laws): [Philip Luty Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Luty)

So - TL;DR - if the knowledge isn't lost and they have access to the right measuring equipment - then any modern firearm is able to be made, it will just take a lot longer than current times.

Comment: I've gotta step in an down vote unless you can provide some cittions. Knowing about electricity and *knowing how to operate an electrical generation plant* are two very, very different things. With so few people, it might not even be possible (whether or not it could would require the OP to specifically explain the limits of destruction and actual population counts around the world, this is a very optimistic answer.

Comment: So, we can have a repetition rifle (even full auto) and casings, but we cant have mass production. All hand made in 1-2 days of work? What about the chemistry for good smokeless powder?

Comment: @JBH - I mean, I included the Citation of the Owen submachine gun and the Luty Submachine gun - there's also the Shinzo Abe homemade 'shotgun' (which was entirely self-made, including the explosive) - OP indicated that Knowledge was preserved - which I'm reading as the knowledge of metalworking and engineering is mostly preserved. Even if we assume that we go back nearly 100 years (whilst we build up enough precision tooling) - we are still at 1920s era tech - so Thompson SMGs, M1 Garand, all manner of repeating (Bolt and Lever action) firearms are available.

Comment: @user2929416 - I mean, depending on how widespread the devastation is - sure. In terms of Firearms technology, most of the major technical innovations are between 70-100 years old. The AK47, as an example was made in 1947. The major changes in recent times is speed of production, Optics and the cost of accuracy - it's now economically viable to make a sub-MOA AR platform (for example) and to make an optic to take advantage of that. IIRC, the Lee Enfield action was initially designed for Black Powder cased ammunition, before moving to Cordite, then smokeless.

Comment: @user2929416 - If we restrict to just Black Powder (the simplest) - then technically it is still possible for Semi/Full Auto firearms - however the issue is that Black Powder has increased fowling that ends up gunking up the actions - meaning that it would be technically possible to do, but practically of dubious benefit. Also forgot to add Hand-Cranked Gatling guns would be another more realistic option.

Comment: Even if an entire library with all the world's knowledge is preserved and people could quickly familiarize themselves with any topic, there are dependencies on all manufacturing today. My example of a power generation plant is salient. They don't run on automatic. They need maintenance and oversight. And given the destruction, the power grid has been compromised to some degree. So there's no way to manufacture those weapons you mention because all manufacturing today depends on electricity. I'm happy to change my vote, but you'll need to address those dependencies (there are many)...

Comment: ... or explain how quickly the world's population can re-establish earlier manufacturing (black smithing... steam power...) that almost no one knows about today (why would we?).

Comment: @JBH - okay, Firearms have existed in much their current form from about the 1500s. Electricity, as a common Industrial usage is really from 1900s. Repeating Firearms (Bolt Action, Lever Action) all pre-existed Electricity. Even if we go back to Blacksmithing, that's still flintlock muskets - and that is mainly a product of inability to control tolerances. If precision measuring equipment (Reference plates, Vernier Calipers and Micrometers) are available - then there is no reason why simply blow-back submachine guns aren't possible - again, see the PA Luty gun and the below post from TCAT117

Comment: @TheDemonLord I just helped a friend write a book about the history of firearms. The technology used to make weapons in the 1500s hasn't been used by any but a vanishing handful of hobbyists since the late 1700s. Every commercial firearm today uses computer-controlled precision manufacturing. I apologize, but you're ignoring how honking hard it would be for someone to *reinvent* how to make a 1500s musket. All I have to do is look at my father-in-law's slide rule or an abacus to know that my degree in electrical engineering isn't worth much when it comes to re-learning how to use those tools.

Comment: @JBH - So, I agree that compared to the mid 20th century, the Hobby Machinist and the Commercial machinist are in decline - I also concede that if the knowledge was just held in books it would be difficult. The key word though is difficult. There are plenty of ad-hoc garage produced weapons - some like the Luty just using off-the shelf components, others like the L96 or Barret .50cal were originally built in someone's garage/shed. There is no requirement for Firearm making to use electricity - the biggest factor is precision measuring - the rest can be done with hand tools as per below.

Comment: As I said, citations please. I want proof that the L96 or Barret .50cal were manufactured without milling machines, precision forges, and electricity. *Where* isn't the problem. *Resources...* that's the problem.

Comment: @JBH - So, the PA Luty Submachine gun fulfills your requirement: https://thehomegunsmith.com/backcover.shtml - here's the excerpt where he says exactly what you are talking about the Luty "regardless of facilities". The L96 https://accuracyinternational.com/assets/ai-history-2018.pdf was originally built in a shed by 2 Daves. They don't elaborate on what was in the shed, but a precision forge is out of the question. A Mill and a Lathe, maybe - but both of those aren't overly complex - hand/foot powered lathes are possible, even for metalworking.

Answer (score 1):

**boy discuss tactic, proffesional talk logistic**

the real questions are how far in the future are we and what level of destruction are we talking about.

what a lot of suggestion in comment seem to forget is that all of those more "ancient" weapon were product of their time and industrial capacity. with the current knowledge and availability of materials.

**day one warband**

If we assume you are going for a very classical  (and i would argue quite wrong) post apo setting with only a bit of time after the cataclysme with everybody being alone or in small raider band (madmax organisation at best). in that case actual production is unthinkable as it would be too dependent on the skill of everybody

then your people would be very unlikely  to make weapon from absolute scratch, ammo and weapon can be conservated for a very long time are and are higly unlickely (look at the soviet stockpile) "rudimentary" lace and metal workshop, even without electrical power can  maintain and work out rudimentary replacement for  decades for those to be entierly depleted.

There are modern weaponsmithing manual that let you craft  guns with part & tool  that you can find in a bikeshop. from the extremly rudimentary pipe shotgun to the liberator or the infamous homemade weapon used  in the shinzo abe attack. with scavenged scrap you  can "easly" make  all kind of non gas operated weapons. for all of those improvised weapon the most classical  design is break action, regardless of the type of ammo.

material are a non issue too at this point, you can just bend over and scrap  a lot of very high quality material in the remain of civilisation.

**back to society**

If you are aiming for something further in the future where some society and town have started to form again, you can start talking about production per say. there it's up to you how long in the future we are and how much decay we got. but the limiting factor will be how liked those  sedentarized society will be connected, as to talk production we will need established society that can industrialized.

knowledge will definitly be retained enough to never go back further than  pre factory system, system that was  alimented by waterweel before the steam engine replaced it.

so if you have a society with enough of a backbone to create industry, i would assume that  their weapon level would be between america's civile war gun  and WW1 riffle.

Answer (score 1):

**Manufacture doesn't require advanced tools**

Firearms and ammunition are not particularly difficult to make, and do not require machine tooling to produce. In WW2 partisans in europe were making submachineguns in basements and garages using only hand tools and fairly primitive machine tools. I actually reproduced one of these designs myself once (it is legal to do so where I live.) It took me about two weeks, and the most advanced tool I used was an arc welder, with the bulk of the work being done using hack saws, hand files, and sand paper. The welding was done for convenience, it could have easily been accomplished using rivets. The end result was a remarkably functional (if rather crude) weapon, pictured here:

[image: Aside from the accessories this was fully hand made]

That said, making firearms in such a manner does create a few issues. First, parts interchangeability is limited or zero. That doesn't seem like a big deal until you realize that this creates logistical nightmares for groups like organized militaries. The second issue is quality control. Its going to vary widely between examples of the same model. The third is labor cost. It took me a solid 2 weeks of vacation putting in 12 hour days to produce. A skilled and properly tooled machinist could probably crank out a dozen or more in that time frame just by himself, and they'd be higher quality with few or none of the issues doing it the way I did would have.

**Ammunition**

Again, the technology level required to produce ammunition is not high. Its basically just high-school chemistry and basic machining. You could produce metallic casings using a hand operated press and a series of dies to press-form the brass (the dies themselves require machining but a milling machine isn't exactly high tech either.) The issue here will again be labor cost. Ammo made this way will be time consuming, probably done in much smaller batches, and likely very expensive relative to what ammo costs today.

**conclusion**

There really isn't any reason why a post-apocalyptic society wouldn't be able to produce guns and ammunition. They probably wouldn't be very high tech, and they would probably be rather expensive, but perfectly functional firearms are not particularly difficult to make.

Comment: An optic and bipod on what looks like a variant of a Sten sub machine gun... I love everything about that picture.

Comment: Thanks! I call him stan!